# How to call Delete Web API from C# code with Attribute Routing Enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a variety of APIs set up in my project, and most of them are working at this point. However, I'm struggling to get the `DELETE` API working on a button click in my .aspx page.

I have this code for the `DELETE` api, including my attribute route that I created:

```
public class ReviewController : ApiController
{
    private ReviewAPIModel db = new ReviewAPIModel();

    [Route("api/Review/delete/{id}")]
    [HttpDelete]
    [ResponseType(typeof(review))]
    public IHttpActionResult Deletereview(int id)
    {
        review review = db.review.Find(id);
        if (review == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.review.Remove(review);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(review);
    }
}
```

I am sure that my attribute routing is enabled correctly.

I have this code for my button click:

```
    protected void repReviews_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:#####/api/review/delete");

                var deleteTask = client.DeleteAsync(Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument));
                deleteTask.Wait();

                var result = deleteTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                     Response.Redirect("MyReviews.aspx");
                }

                Response.Redirect("MyReviews.aspx");

            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to run the code by clicking the button, it runs through it all (I checked by using breakpoints). However, the record is not deleted from the database, and is still on the screen.

All of the guidance that I've found for this kind of scenario is either A) using a SQL Data Source, or B) not using Attribute Routing (with A) being the primary issue with finding a helpful Google result).

How do I make these two things mesh together?

ETA: DB Context:

```
public partial class ReviewAPIModel : DbContext
{
    public ReviewAPIModel()
        : base("name=ReviewAPIModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<review> review { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Also to be clear. when you say it is not working, what is actually happening as opposed to what is expected?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "avoid using blocking calls". I'm mostly copy/pasting from various web sources. 

As far as "not working"--when I click the button that the function is tied to, it runs the function (I'm able to step through each of the steps with breakpoints put in), but it doesn't actually delete anything. It makes it through all the steps with no errors, but the record is not removed from the database.

Comment: what value of `Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument)`?

Comment: @phroureo Right you see that was not clear from the original question. I suggest you update that detail into the question.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk That value is passed from the Repeater object that the button is tied to. I've verified that the value being passed is correct.

Comment: @phroureo Show the API controller definition along with the db context and how it is injected.

Comment: @Nkosi the API Controller is already in the question and I'm not sure why you need the db context.

Comment: @phroureo One API action is in the question not the controller. Also seeing as the db is the one not removing the record then stands to reason we should see how it relates to the controller.

Comment: Okay, I've added them both to the question. I don't think either of those things are the issue, because the dbcontext works for the other API's I'm using (also, the GET api is confirmed working in other context, so I didn't include it).

Comment: @phroureo ok so you say the delete is no working. Sure Gets work. Do updates also show correctly? As in after updating some value, the same is reflected after the update when a get is done?

Comment: I'm not sure about `POST` but I can `PUT` without issues.

Comment: I am curious though with your client side code. the button click redirects to the same page whether call was successful or not. You certain the path flows to the remove and save of the API on the server?. Just trying to cover all bases here as we troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Yes, I've stepped through the code with breakpoints. I believe that the issue is with the `client.deleteAsync` line in the code. I'm not sure that the parameter I'm passing is correct (While it steps through and the browser and Visual Studio don't give me errors, one of the variables tells me it's a 405 error and can't find the method).

Comment: @phroureo only just saw you comment. I provided a suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it would seem that the problem is not that the database is not removing the item. It is that the request's HTTP Verb (Delete) is not being accepted by the web server (HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed), even though you have the `[HttpDelete]` attribute on the action.

My suggestion would be to include the `[AcceptVerbs]` attribute on the action.

```
[Route("api/Review/delete/{id:int}")]
[HttpDelete]
[AcceptVerbs("DELETE")] //<-- ADD THIS
[ResponseType(typeof(review))]
public IHttpActionResult Deletereview(int id) {
    review review = db.review.Find(id);
    if (review == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }

    db.review.Remove(review);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(review);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the `review review = db.review.Find(id);` line that says ": 'The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
Parameter name: keyValues'" Which is a different error than before, so thanks for that help lol

Comment: @phroureo Good. That is a new error, which means that it is finally hitting the web service.

Comment: It looks like the foreign keys that were in the table were also marked as keys. I've removed that, and it looks like it's working now! Thank you so much for the help!